# Connection reset by peer - SSL_connect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parse-platform, https, openssl

Sometime i got this error when i send Https request from RAILS server and sometimes works.
I want to understand the reason behind not working and also how it's working sometimes.

My code:

```
require 'net/http'
require "uri"
require 'net/https'

def parse_query(classname, conditions)
    url = "https://link"
    uri = URI.parse(url)
    http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
    http.use_ssl = true
    http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
    request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
    request["X-Parse-Application-Id"] = "some data"
    request["X-Parse-REST-API-Key"] = "some data"
    request["Content-Type"] = "application/json"

    response = http.request(request)
end
```

Rails version = 4.2.1
Ruby version = 2.2.1